# Eclipse editor plugin: "ERROR" when opening file outside project

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I'm developing an editor plugin for eclipse. It works fine on files within eclipse projects, but when an external file is opened via the "File -> Open File" menu (which works file with, e.g. Java files), I get a page displaying nothing but a horizontal blue line and the word "ERROR". The Error Log of eclipse is empty, as is the log file in the .metadata directory.

What could cause this? How can I diagnose the error when I have no error message that tells me where to look? There doesn't seem to be a way to get more detailed logging from eclipse.

**Edit:**

I've found that the source of the problem is close to what jamesh mentioned, but not a ClassCastException - there simply is no `IDocument` instance for the text viewer to display because `StorageDocumentProvider.createDocument()` returns null. The reason for this is that  it only knows how to create documents for instances of `org.eclipse.ui.IStorageEditorInput`, but in this case it gets an instance of `org.eclipse.ui.ide.FileStoreEditorInput`, which does not implement that interface, but instead implements `org.eclipse.ui.IURIEditorInput`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same probleam and finally found solution working for me.
You have to provide 2 different document providers - first extending **FileDocumentProvider** for files inside your workbench, and second extending **TextFileDocumentProvider** for other resources outside your workspace. Then you register the right provider acording to the input in your editors **doSetInput** method like this:

```
private IDocumentProvider createDocumentProvider(IEditorInput input) {
    if(input instanceof IFileEditorInput){
        return new XMLTextDocumentProvider();
    } else if(input instanceof IStorageEditorInput){
        return new XMLFileDocumentProvider();
    } else {
        return new XMLTextDocumentProvider();
    }
}

@Override
protected final void doSetInput(IEditorInput input) throws CoreException {
    setDocumentProvider(createDocumentProvider(input));
    super.doSetInput(input);
}
```

then in your new document provider (extending TextFileDocumentProvider) insert somethnig like this:

```
protected FileInfo createFileInfo(Object element) throws CoreException {
        FileInfo info = super.createFileInfo(element);
        if(info==null){
            info = createEmptyFileInfo();
        }
        IDocument document = info.fTextFileBuffer.getDocument();
        if (document != null) {

            /* register your partitioner and other things here 
                       same way as in your fisrt document provider */
        }
        return info;
    }
```

This works for me :) Finally I have to mention, that I'm not so clever and that I copied this solution from project Amateras (Opensource HTML editor plugin for eclipse)

Comment: Thanks for this! I was really frustrated that the Editor Plug-in example (Eclipse 3.7) didn't work out of the box with non-workspace files. FYI, in 3.7, the type checking in this code doesn't work as-is. It works if you instead do: `instanceof IFileEditorInput` => XMLFileDocumentProvider, `else` => XMLTextDocumentProvider. Furthermore, it also works if you simply use the XMLTextDocumentProvider (i.e. a TextFileDocumentProvider) in both cases. More info [in this forum post](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t98253.html#92158543). I'm not sure of a reason to extend FileDocumentProvider.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little away from the source code at the moment, though I suspect the problem is a `ClassCastException`:

- For a workspace file, the `IEditorInput` is `org.eclipse.ui.IFileEditorInput`.
- For a local non-workspace file, the `IEditorInput` is `org.eclipse.ui.IStorageEditorInput`

The difference is in how you get the contents from the `IEditorInput`. The JDT does an explicit `instanceof` check to make the switch.

I don't think that the `getAdapter(Class clazz)` will return a `java.io.InputStream` if you offer it.

I don't quite understand why they do it like this, but it feels ugly.

**Edit:**
A more general point about debugging eclipse apps - it's really very useful to try and assemble all your logs into one place (i.e. the console).

To do this, make sure you use the command line options `-console` and `-consoleLog`. The latter has helped save countless hours of time. If you haven't already, learn the most basic things about how to use the console (`ss` and `start` are my most often used). This will save some more time diagnosing a certain class of problem.

Comment: That definitely sounds like it could be the cause - will check that  when I can (I'm away from that code right now as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try creating a JAVA file using the editor, outside the workspace?

When calling the editor with the file path, concat "file://" at the beginning of the file path.e.g: if the path is C://temp//Sample.java, then modify it as file://C://temp//Sample.java.

Comment: I'm not calling the editor at all, I'm opening a file via eclipse's menu. It's a specific file type whose extension causes it to be opened in my editor plugin. I merely mentioned Java as an example of an editor where this works.