# Eclipse 3.7 plugin editor template does not run out of the box

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to build a simple custom editor in the Eclipse environment.  To get started, I created a new plugin project with the "Plug-in with an editor" template.

[image]

The only thing I changed was the target extension, to .stt files.  I ran the app and tried to open a text file containing basic lines of text and this is what I get:

[image]

There is nothing in the Error Log as you can see.  There are no errors in the Console in the development environment.  How am I supposed to determine what "Error" means?

EDIT:  Same problem on a fresh Eclipse 3.6 install too.

Comment: Can you verify it is your editor that is trying to open it? Right-click and do a Open With. If it is your editor set a break point at the instantiation of your editor part.

Comment: @Andrew - thanks your comment sparked the key idea that solved it... I was trying to open sample files outside of the workspace using File -> Open rather than opening files inside of a project in the workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew's comment above got me on the right track... The solution to the problem lies with how Eclipse treats opening files external to the workspace differently than files inside projects in the workspace.  Who would have thought?

The complete answer to how to code your editor is found here:

[Eclipse editor plugin: "ERROR" when opening file outside project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455210/eclipse-editor-plugin-error-when-opening-file-outside-project)